# Consultar se há dados na coluna

Tags: php, mysql

Tem como fazer uma verificação para saber se existe dados dentro de uma coluna em uma tabela?

Quero fazer uma verificação e se existir dados na coluna ele exibe uma `div`.

Eu conheço o `mysql_num_rows` para somar os dados que foram buscados, mas queria saber se tem como eu verificar dados dentro de uma coluna.

Comment: `<?php if (!empty($exibe_painel_usuarios_um [ "twitter" ]))` basta negar

Comment: Resolvido, echo "<div class=\"equipe_redes_twitter\">".$exibe_painel_usuarios_um [ "twitter" ]."</div>";

Comment: Thanks por a ajuda.

Comment: De boa veiow. \o

Answer (score -1):

Se é para verificar apenas uma coluna, faça um `SELECT` contando os resultados, usando como atributo, se a coluna não é vazia (`IS NOT NULL`), na clausula `WHERE`. Assim terá como saber se existem resultados. No exemplo a seguir esta como validar se existem registros para a coluna, para fazer seu select deverá colocar todos itens que são necessários para a consulta que estava fazendo, para desta forma obter o resultado correto.

```
SELECT count(COLUNA) as TOTAL FROM TABLEA WHERE COLUNA IS NOT NULL;
```

Neste caso você pegara o resultado do select com o alias "`TOTAL`" e se for diferente de `0`, então exiba os resultados, provenientes de outro `SELECT` preferêncialmente.

Fazendo da forma que esta acima irá reduzir consumo do `MYSQL`, tendo em vista que da outra forma irá retornar um linha da tabela toda, para no final de a coluna estar vazia ignora-la. Embora se usar o `IS NOT NULL` e colocar a coluna mesmo no mysql também não ira dar erro, porém neste caso será necessário usar o `mysql_num_rows` e isso consumiria mais recursos que efetuar um `count` em um campo.

Comment: Is not null não funciona se for um caso de campo vazio ' '.